# 'acpi -t' command does not show thermal information

Tags: battery, acpi, temperature, sensors

I am trying to get thermal information for my laptop using `acpi -t` command.

Unfortunately, It doesn't show thermal information. Here is output of the command `acpi -V`.

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 98%
Battery 0: design capacity 4400 mAh, last full capacity 4399 mAh = 99%
Adapter 0: on-line
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 2: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 3: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

Is acpi package broken or something? 
I have also install `lm-sensors` and `psensor` package as well recently.

`acpi -t` output:

```
~$ acpi -t  
~$
```

`sensors` output:

```
coretemp-isa-0000  
Adapter: ISA adapter  
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  
Core 1:         +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

dell_smm-virtual-0  
Adapter: Virtual device  
fan1:        2600 RPM
```

`lsmod`:
[link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25062164/)

`/etc/sensors3.conf`:
[link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25062175/)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have added the output to the post.

Comment: `acpi -t` doesn't output anything. `sensors` showing only cpu temperature. I have added output to the post.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for correction. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: I have the same experience on my machine. `sensors` can use the `it87` (`it8721-isa-0290`) and `k10temp-pci-00c3` to get temperature information, but my computer seems to be missing ACPI thermal zones even though ACPI Thermal is enabled in the kernel. Maybe some computers with buggy ACPI or old implementations from before it was popular to have thermal zones just don’t have it?